# High school Math: Finding the Median

Tags: statistics, median

I have a problem trying to understand the following two questions:

[image: Question 1]
[image: Question 2]

In question 1, the median is found at the 50% of the total group. However, this strategy doesn't work for question 2. Why?

Answer (score 1):

1) Order the percentages from Group 2 in ascending order.

3%, 4%, 5%, 6%, 10%, 11%, 21%

2) As there are 7 terms, The median will be the 4th term (6%)

3) 6% of 400 people in group 2 = 24 people

Answer (score 1):

> In question 1, median is found at the 50% of the total group. However,
>   this strategy doesn't work for question 2. Why?

They're totally different questions. Question 1 asks for the "median area" (i.e., the median of the original variable), whereas Question 2 asks for "the medians of the numbers of people in group 2". I might opine that Question 1 has real-world application, while Question 2 is made-up busywork, and it's not even phrased correctly.

For Question 1, all of the 8000 apartments have a quantitative value for area, and if they were listed in order, the median would be at or close to the 4000th entry in the list; that is, after counting 50% of the list. Since the classes in the table are numerically increasing, we can use this to effectively count off the first 50% of the data and see which class it must fall in (namely after accounting for 5% + 18% + 23% + 4%, which puts us in the 4th class as indicated). This is something that can be practically useful; deducing the median of a data set when not all of the data is on display.

But in Question 2, the variable for the people in the study is a qualitative ailment, "Asthma, Hay Fever", etc. No median exists for such a data set, and also the classes are not in increasing value order (as they are non-numerical), so it doesn't even vaguely resemble Question 1. Instead, the questioner is simply drawing attention to the table of percentages for Group 2 and asking for the median of *those numbers in the table*, assuming they were converted from percents to raw counts -- not the median of the original variable (which doesn't exist). I can't think of how this would be useful statistically; it's just a made-up exercise with some found numbers. So in this case the question requires that you convert the listed percents to counts ($21\% \times 400 = 84$, etc.), sort those numbers, and take the middle value in accordance with the definition of the mean.

Comment: instead of converting the percentages to number of people beforehand, why not sort the percentages first, find the middle term and then convert that middle term to number of people? In this case, 6% is the middle, so 6%*400=24

Comment: Sure, it's equivalent. Of course, that's orthogonal to answering the question of "However, this strategy [for question 1] doesn't work for question 2. Why?"

Comment: good point. upvoted

Comment: Added quote to clarify the exact question being answered.